# How could a sister of battle win against a necron army?

Tags: warhammer-40k

So, I've read the book *Hammer and Anvil* by James Swallow and I'm a bit confused.

I really like the Adepta Sororitas, but even so I'm still puzzled as how a simple sister could actually win against an army of necron or win against a necron warlord.

In the book, at the end:

> The sisters fight against a tech-priest (or was it a cryptek?).

As I know even a whole platoon of sisters shouldn't be able to win against that.

So my question is: Was it the relic (The hammer and anvil) that gave them the strength to win? I mean, it's not really explained, it said something like it filled the sister with hope, but it shouldn't be enough, is there a real effect?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of stories where a lone hero (or small team of heroes) goes up against overwhelming odds and somehow manages to win in the end.  Including cases where the opposing army has tanks, planes, giant robots and other "hard targets."  Is there a particular reason why this example is more difficult to believe than usual?

Comment: @Steve-O - Well i do know that there is a lot of stories like this one, but i actually wanted to put the emphasis on the relic part (i may have been a bit misleading on the question). Most of the relics have actually a direct effect (too many examples, but you should see my point). I wanted to know if _The Hammer and Anvil_ actually played a direct part in the victory/escape of the sisters. I don't remember any relic like this one in the tabletop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The relic](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Hammer_and_Anvil) was just a book with no special properties except sermons written by Saint Katherine's own hand. So how could it help Sisters?  It reinforced their faith and Sisters of Battle basically weaponised faith in Emperor using it to purge all that is unclean in His eyes.

For Sisters, it was a symbol, that the Emperor is with them, which gave them the strength to fight the Necron,  just like in the "[Sharpe's Rifles](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108108/)" hanging an old banner from a church gave the whole country strength to rise against invaders.

As to book vs game reality - well, the power of heroes is as strong as the plot demands. In one book a few Space Marines can capture the whole planet from the hands of the enemy, in another, they will be dying in hundreds (the great "Gaunt's Ghost" series can be good example: In one book commissar-colonel Ibram Gaunt mentions that he killed 8 Chaos Space Marines, in another 3 marines have enough firepower to almost capture the whole space fort)

Comment: "You expect them to fight for a rag on a pole?" 

"You do Richard, you do"

Love the Sharpe reference +1!